# How to Create DataTable in LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

How to create DataTable in LINQ? In SQL Statements i used

```
DataTable dt;
dt = con.openDataTableQuery("SELECT TransactionID FROM HeaderTransaction");
```

How about in LINQ? Can you give an example?

Comment: Which kind of "LINQ" are you asking about? LINQ to SharePoint? LINQ to Objects? And why do you want a `DataTable`?

Comment: This is a very poor quality question.  The basic premise has been asked and answered many times before.  Brief questions without anything that shows you have tried to solve the problem by yourself will normally get downvoted and closed.

Answer (score -2):

Please see the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386921%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for LINQ to DataSet, examples can be found on the page.

The following is an example emulating your SQL code.

```
// Add a reference to System.Data.DataSetExtensions

// Query the headerTransaction table to select all items with TransactionID == 1, as an example, use your own value(s)
IEnumerable<DataRow> query =
from headers in headerTransaction.AsEnumerable()
where order.Field<int>("TransactionID") = 1
select order;

// Create a table from the query. 
DataTable headersIdQuery = query.CopyToDataTable<DataRow>();
```

AsEnumerable() returns IEnumerable. As you asked for a DataTable, we convert IEnumerable to a DataTable, using CopyToDataTable().

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: Good point. Thanks Nathan, I'll incorporate that into my answers in the future (and edit this one)